# How to setTextColor on newButton?

Tags: fonts, colors, lua, coronasdk

How can I change font color for `widget.newButton`?

What I've tried:

```
    playBtn = widget.newButton{
        left = display.contentCenterX,
        top = 0,
        id = "playbutton",
        label = "Play",
        emboss=true,
        width = 250,
        height = 70,
        fontSize = 30,
        defaultFile = "media/button-2.png",
        overFile = "media/button-2.png",
        onEvent = playBtnF
    }

playBtn:setTextColor( 0, 255, 255 )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello if it's the color for the label I believe you can use `labelColor` inside of the options to set the color of the label see more in [corona widget.newButton()](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newButton.html).

Example:

```
playBtn = widget.newButton{
        left = display.contentCenterX,
        top = 0,
        id = "playbutton",
        label = "Play",
        labelColor = { default={ 1, 1, 1 }, over={ 0, 0, 0, 0.5 } }, // This is the option
        emboss=true,
        width = 250,
        height = 70,
        fontSize = 30,
        defaultFile = "media/button-2.png",
        overFile = "media/button-2.png",
        onEvent = playBtnF
    }
```

If you're not using corona API library please specify what library you're using. Hope this helps.